# How to verify that the source code is copied from web

Tags: security, checksum, sha, code-access-security

I am building a web tool to check whether the submitted content is taken from web or is it submitter own work. A plagiarism detector.

I have some idea that I can generated check sum and use that as a key to compare with other entries. However, if someone has made some small changes like including/removing comments, changing variables/function name and so on then the checksum will be different, so this approach won't work.

Any suggestions for a better way?

Comment: What do you know about the data submitted ? You cant scan the entire web and search for the content ...

Comment: ye that's absolutely fine...but I can search some key word of problem statement on the web looking for some solution (source code) and then make a comparison up to some extent.

Comment: try and use a service that uses semantics

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Plagiarism detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism_detection) is a special case of similarity detection. This is a big field of study that's almost as old as computer science its self. There is a *lot* of published research, and there just isn't a single simple answer.

See, eg, [a Google Scholar search for "code similarity plagiarism"](http://scholar.google.com.au/scholar?q=code+similarity+plagiarism&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5) or ["plagiarism detection"](http://scholar.google.com.au/scholar?q=plagiarism+detection&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5). Regular Google searches for things like ["source code similarity detection algorithm"](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=source+code+similarity+detection+algorithm) can also be useful.

There are plenty of [existing tools](http://www.ics.heacademy.ac.uk/resources/assessment/plagiarism/detectiontools_sourcecode.html) in the space, too, so I'm surprised you're trying to write your own.

As you've noted, a check-sum won't do the job unless the code is perfectly identical. Techniques that can help include:

- Building word-frequency histograms and comparing them
- Extracting comment text and looking for copied comments using text-substring matching
- Extracting variable, class and method names and looking for other code that uses the same names. You have to do a lot of correction for "obvious" names that everyone will choose, and for names that're dictated by the problem, like implementing a particular interface or API. Private class member variables and the local variables inside a function or method are the most useful to compare. You will need the help of a compiler or at least syntax parser for the language to extract these.
- Looking for differences in indenting style. Did the user use all-spaces indenting, except for this one function that's indented with tabs?
- Comparing parse trees or token streams to strip out the effects of formatting. You'd usually have to compare individual functions, etc, not just the code as a whole.
- ... and lots more

What you'll have to do is produce a report that weighs all these factors and others and presents them to a human so the human can make a decision. Your tool should explain *why* it thinks two results are similar, not just that they are similar.

Comment: Is it Plagarism or Plagiarism ?

Comment: @IonutFlaviusPogacian I've apparently *always* misread that without realising. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: The "existing tools" link no longer works @CraigRinger

Answer (score 0):

How i would aproach this, and custom enhancements can be added lately:

Remove everything that is not a letter or number;

Use `explode()` with empty space character as delimiter and find all the words; now you know how many words you have in that article;

Now, you must find out how many times a word apears in that article, and increase the word indicator each time that word is found in the text;

Store this into an array, like:

```
$words['wordX']++;
```

Do this also with the seccond article that you want to check with;

Now, compare them; You know the original data; some conclusions ca be made at this step;

Using the big characters, like J from John, F from Feudalism, you can also make some conclusions;

From here you may know if the article is about the same thing, and this could be the real step #1

Now, somehow you have to parse both articles, word by word, in the same time, and see the differecnce beetween them.

A student can add a own "original" sentence after each sentence/paragraph found in the original article.

Make sure that if you advance to much in the parsing process on one of the articles, you somehow keep a balanced parsing process and try to parse the seccond article until you reach that balance.

i see 2 `for` instructions, maybe 3, or instead of 3, a function that tryes to keep the balance in the parsing process.

Also, you have to use `explode()` and check sentence by sentence, and word by word from each sentence and find the similarity.

I am sure that you get the idea, but i say again, you cant parse the entire WWW.

Comment: thnkx....actually let me elaborate a bit more..I am putting an algorithmic challenge in the college portal..programmers are free to discuss and post the solution....so here I am trying to verify their submission against some of the submission avail on different forum/blog.

Comment: the best way to check for plagiarism is to check word by word, sentence by sentence and use the original article as a reference point on whatever parsing process your students develop